# Java Post Request Not Working

Tags: java, post, request

Why does this not work? I have also tried using HttpURLConnection class however this did not work either. The php page cannot find the posted data. 
Note: im new to post requests with java.

```
public static String GetURL(String inUrl, String post) {
    String inputLine = "";
    try {
        if (!inUrl.contains("http")) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid URL");
        } else {
            Log.writeLog(inUrl);
            URL url = new URL(inUrl);

            //send post
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection(); 
            //connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
            connection.connect();

            OutputStream wr = connection.getOutputStream();
            wr.write(post.getBytes());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            inputLine = in.readLine();
            in.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.writeLog("Error getting url.");
    }

    return inputLine;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify the error, it is hard for me to see where you went wrong.

However, I think it would be a lot easier to use an abstraction like [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/index.html). Your code would look like this:

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder()
        .setURI(inUrl)
        .addHeader("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8")
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .build();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
httpPost.setEntity(post);
```

Much cleaner than dealing with the low-level details of streams and connections.